# worst performance in numerical integration in ver. 11.1

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I would like to know if anyone of you have experienced slow down performance in numerical integration. I have tested this code in ver. 11 and ver. 11.1:

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[NIntegrate[
       Exp[-2 π I*(4 1.4 x 0.33)], {y, -Sqrt[1 - 0.33^2], 
        Sqrt[1 - 0.33^2]}, {x, -Sqrt[1 - y^2] + 0.33, 
        Sqrt[1 - y^2] - 0.33}, 
       Method -> {"MultiPeriodic", 
         "SymbolicProcessing" -> Automatic}]
```

The computed times are (in secs):

ver 11: `0.0342449`

ver 11.1: `0.0841432`

which are significantly slower in the latest version. Mathematica runs in a PC Intel i7 QuadCore 3.1 Ghz 16GB RAM, Windows 7.

Any check/comment/suggestion/advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You have lots of functions combined here.  Please start by breaking things down: which one of them got slower?  In particular: get rid of parallelization if it is not necessary.

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried to calculate `First@AbsoluteTiming[
    ClearSystemCache[]; NIntegrate[
      Exp[-2 \[Pi] I*(4 # x 0.33)], {y, -Sqrt[1 - 0.33^2], Sqrt[
       1 - 0.33^2]}, {x, -Sqrt[1 - y^2] + 0.33, Sqrt[1 - y^2] - 0.33},
       Method -> {"MultiPeriodic", 
        "SymbolicProcessing" -> Automatic}]] & /@ {1.4, 2.7}` in both versions, as suggested. I obtained `{0.0385489, 0.0294288}` and `{0.0920457, 0.0757555}`. About three times slower. Parallelization does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: My point is that the example you give in the post is very complex. Please reduce it (within the post, not in a comment) to show only the relevant parts.  This is something that *must* be done before any answer can be written, and also something that you can do yourself (instead of a person who would answer).

Comment: @Szabolcs what you mean with "complex"? I will try to edit the question.

Comment: If you use 10 functions, I can't tell which is slow. If you use 1, it is obvious which is slow.  Parallelization performance is known to be fickle. `Quiet` may be hiding messages which affect performance.  Why are you including these in the example?  They are either relevant, in which case you should state that. Or they aren't, which means you should remove them.

Comment: Please also look up what is a [complete minimal example](http://sscce.org/) and why it is important to construct one when asking questions.

Comment: Have you tried `NIntegrate[Exp[-2 π I*(4 1.4 x 0.33)], {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[(x + 0.33)^2 < 1 - y^2 && (x - 0.33)^2 < 1 - y^2, {x, y}]]`?

Comment: @J.M. your alternative seems to be comparable. However, an explanation of why my strategy does not work is needed, particularly when I have many of those integrals programmed in that way previously.

Comment: In V11.0, I get a `Greater::nord` message. The numerical values are different, too. Do you know which is more accurate?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I get the same error in V11.0. My attempts tell me that changing 0.33 to other values such as 0.1 or 0.2, the results agree. However in my application numerical result within 3 decimal places is quite enough. By the way, I know that the integral should return real values, and the real part agrees with the numerical result got by other non integral calculation. Anyway, I realize that the accuracy is an issue too.